# Reverse for 'update' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Manager/update/$']

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

After creating edit button in home.html, I've been getting this error all the time and have no idea how to resolve it.

**views.py**

```
def siteUpdate(request, id_):
site=get_object_or_404(Site_data,id=id_)
if request.POST=="POST":
    form=SiteForm(request.POST,instance=site)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.log_name=request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('Manager:home.html')
else:
    form=SiteForm(instance=site)
    site = {

        'form':form
    }
    return render(request,'Manager/siteform.html',sie)
```

**models.py**

```
class Site_data(models.Model):
log_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
site_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
site_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
site_login = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name='Manager'

urlpatterns = [

path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('create/', views.siteCreate, name='create'),
path('update/', views.siteUpdate, name='update')

]
```

**home.html**

```
{% for site in sites %}
<td>{{site.site_name}}</td>
<td>{{site.site_url}}</td>
<td>{{site.site_login}}</td>
<td>{{site.site_password}}</td>
<td><a href="{% url 'Manager:update' site.id %}"><button 
type="button">Edit</button></a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually call the update view with an the ID `site.id` in `<a href="{% url 'Manager:update' site.id %}">`, however your path URL does not contain the ID.

```
path('update/', views.siteUpdate, name='update')
```

Seeing your view `def siteUpdate(request, id_):` the correct way to call it is the following:

It would become:

```
path('update/<int:id_>', views.siteUpdate, name='update')
```